# Will this flip my CIImage vertically?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-image

I'm very frustrated. Why won't this flip my CIImage vertically?

```
recognizedImage = [recognizedImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1), 0, recognizedImage.extent.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget to add `CoreImage.framework` to your project.

This works for me:

```
// Load image
UIImage *u = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage"];
// Convert to CIImage
CIImage *c = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:u];
// Apply transform
c = [c imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1), 0, c.extent.size.height)];

// Convert back to UIImage
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
u = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:c fromRect:c.extent]];

// Load the UIImage into the view
[self.imageView setImage:u];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I don't know what I was doing wrong. Probably just needed to sit back and think, haha. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried breaking it up into two parts?

```
myImage = [myImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];
myImage = [myImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, extent.size.height)];
```